# Как сделать чтобы блок сдвигался?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

В общем, хочу сделать так, когда блок chat-options имел ширину, то chat-details сдвигался, то есть, выходил в левую часть, тк я кнопки не вижу. Как поправить такое? Просто margin давать при touch?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.container {
  max-width: 390px;
  height: 844px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.chat {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.chat-details {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

.chat-info {
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.chat-avatar {
  display: block;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.chat-name {
  color: #000;
}

.chat-message {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgb(0 0 0 / 80%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.chat-options {
  display: flex;
}

.btn {
  width: 65px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="chatlist">
    <a href="" class="chatlist-chat chat">
      <div class="chat-details">
        <span class="chat-avatar"></span>
        <div class="chat-info">
          <div class="chat-name">Telegram</div>
          <div class="chat-message">Простое сообщение</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-options">
        <button class="btn btn-1">Вкл. звук</button>
        <button class="btn btn-2">Удалить</button>
        <button class="btn btn-3">В архив</button>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Смотрите, если дать .btn width: 80px; то кнопки выходят за предел, а я хочу чтобы просто chat-details сдвигался влево, а не стоял на месте

Comment: Я, например, ничего не понял. Опишите конкретнее вашу проблему

Comment: У вас для текста `.chat-message` стоит `white-space: nowrap`. Без него все сожмется.